# Issue when converting mysql_fetch array to $wpdb->get results within WP Shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-shortcode

I am looking to deliver a dropdown within the page of a Wordpress Theme connecting to the backend WP Database using $wpdb and ob_start to bring through option values.

In order to do this I have had to convert mysql_fetch array to $wpdb->get results and use a Shortcode generated from a PHP Snippet plugin.

Code -

```
add_shortcode( 'get-city', function () {
    ob_start(); ?>
   <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->query("SELECT countryid FROM {$wpdb->prefix}city");?>
    <select name="city"> 
    <option>Select City</option> 
    <?php while($row=$wpdb->get_results($results)) {
           echo "<option value>{$row->city}</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    
    return ob_get_clean();
});
```

The shortcode shows no errors and is able to be activated.

The dropdown shows on the page but then no options are presented for a user to select. Nothing is being brought through from the db.

I would really appreciate it if someone could point out the error.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE -

I have amended 'while' to 'foreach' within the code -

```
add_shortcode( 'get-city', function () {
    ob_start(); ?>
   <?php
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->query("SELECT city FROM {$wpdb->prefix}city");?>
    <select name="city"> 
    <option>Select City</option> 
    <?php $rows = $wpdb->get_results($results); foreach( $rows as $row ){
           echo "<option value>{$rows->city}</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    
    return ob_get_clean();
});
```

I still cannot bring values from the backend db.

Many thanks for your response(s) so far.

Comment: Do you know there is a Documentation web site for WP [wpdb::get_results( string $query = null, string $output = OBJECT ): array|object|null)](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/)

Comment: `$wpdb->get_results($results)` is basically a `fetchAll`

Comment: So do something like `$rows = $wpdb->get_results($results); foreach( $rows as $row ){`

Comment: Many thanks for the fast response, I have used foreach as suggested but still do not get any options within the dropdown when the page loads. I'm guessing its to do with the {$row->city} within the option value tags. Appreciate the heads up on the documentation.

Comment: Add the new code to your question under an **UPDATE** title and I will have a look

Comment: `echo "<option value>{$row->city}</option>";` You address the single object returned by the foreach

Comment: Thanks, updated the code as suggested, emptied the cache and reloaded but still the same result. ,no values brought through for the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

`$wpdb->get_results($results)` is basically a fetchAll

> https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_results/

So do this

```
add_shortcode( 'get-city', function () {
    ob_start(); 

    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->query("SELECT city FROM {$wpdb->prefix}city");
?>
    <select name="city"> 
        <option>Select City</option> 
<?php 
    $rows = $wpdb->get_results($results); 
    foreach( $rows as $row ){
        echo "<option value='{$row->city}'>{$row->city}</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    
    return ob_get_clean();
});
```

You may want to put the `id` of the ciry row in the `value` attribute like this. Depends on how its stored and later used

```
echo "<option value='{$row->id}'>{$row->city}</option>";
```

Comment: Sorry missed something, code amended on the `echo "<option value='{$row->city}'>{$row->city}</option>";` line

Comment: Appreciate your advice. Tried both with and without the id. Still no values in the dropdown. Frustrating as it certainly looks like it should work. When loaded 'Select City' appears in the dropdown. When the dropdown is clicked 'Select City appears again  in addition to the appearance in the dropdown without clicking (shows twice on page). It's as though 'Select City ' is an option and nothing dragged through from the db.

Comment: Hmmm I am stumped. Something we are both missing but I dont know what it is right now

Comment: Thanks, just for info, I have checked the backend connection using $wpdb->show_errors();  Page content loaded by php is within a buffer by using ob_start(); The issue is certainly front end.